# Mongodb - sort order of $in

Tags: mongodb, search

From mongodb docs: The $in operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array `{ field: { $in: [<value1>, <value2>, ... <valueN> ] } }`.

Question: How can I get the documents returned in the same order in which they exist in the array passed to the mongo query? (Mongo currently returns them in ascending order of time of creation)

Comment: It depends. Why do you sort by date filed?

Comment: I do not sort by date, mongo does that by default for $in